# Sprite with categoryBitMask still returns 'nil'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have a bullet sprite class in SpriteKit that I would like to collide with an enemy sprite. I set the bullet's bit mask like so:

```
    physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bullet
    physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
    physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
```

(This is in a subclass of SKSpriteNode, which allows me to use physicsBody without a sprite object beforehand.)

Even so, when I print out the bullet's categoryBitMask with,

```
println(physicsBody?.categoryBitMask)
```

it prints out nil. (When I try this with any of the other sprite set up in the same manner, it works fine)

Why is it that even though I set the categoryBitMask, it still prints out nil?

The Physics Category Struct is:

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
static let None      : UInt32 = 0
static let All       : UInt32 = UInt32.max
static let Enemy     : UInt32 = 0b1
static let Bullet    : UInt32 = 0b10
static let Player    : UInt32 = 0b11
static let Wall      : UInt32 = 0b100
static let Star      : UInt32 = 0b101
```

}

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the way you have created the category bit masks is wrong. They should **powers of two** so that it can be tested using a simple `AND operation`.

```
struct PhysicsCategory {

    static let None      : UInt32 = 0
    static let All       : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let Enemy     : UInt32 = 0b01
    static let Bullet    : UInt32 = 0b10
    static let Player    : UInt32 = 0b100
    static let Wall      : UInt32 = 0b1000
    static let Star      : UInt32 = 0b10000

}
```

You have to instantiate the `physicsBody` of the `SKSpriteNode` before setting the `categoryBitMask` bit mask.

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
```

It can be changed to any other shape of your choosing.

Comment: @Acoop does it solve your issue? I have a similar one, but in my case, nodes configured in the same way sometimes do not results in phys callbacks upon contact.